# Browser has not initialized in tabitem with ChromiumWebBrowser WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I have problem with control Cefsharp ChromiumWebBrowser in WPF. Project contain  UserControl and Tabitem which is inside UserControl. When program is running and i move to tabitem control i have exception thrown

> An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in CefSharp.dll but
>   was not handled in user code IBrowser instance is null. Browser has
>   likely not finished initializing or is in the process of disposing.

XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="QuoteHubWPF.Controls.ChromeWebBrowser"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:QuoteHubWPF.Controls"
         xmlns:cefSharp="clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf"
         xmlns:ge="clr-namespace:SourceChord.ResponsiveGrid;assembly=ResponsiveGrid.Wpf"

  mc:Ignorable="d"  ClipToBounds="True">


<cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser Name="chromiumWebBrowser" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"   RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"  Height="360" ClipToBounds="True" Loaded="ChromiumCKEditor_Loaded"  IsBrowserInitializedChanged="browser_IsBrowserInitializedChanged"   FrameLoadEnd="chromiumWebBrowser_FrameLoadEnd"/>
```

.cs

public partial class ChromeWebBrowser : UserControl
    {

```
    public ChromeWebBrowser()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
         chromiumWebBrowser.Address = "html";

    }      

    public string GetHTML()
    {


        var htmlFromPage = chromiumWebBrowser.EvaluateScriptAsync("getDataFromTheEditor", 10000);
```

> here exist exception

```
       var response = htmlFromPage.Result;
        var result = response.Success ? (response.Result ?? "null").ToString() : response.Message;

        return result;

    }
    private void browser_IsBrowserInitializedChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

  some code to run script 


    }   
}
```

Any solution to fix this problem ? Its occurs when run tabitem control.

Update with explained problem 
Thank for quickly answer @amaitland. GetHtml is calling in other viewmodel. So how i can initialize  once again without error with over process ?

NewJobViewModel

```
public void GetHTMLFromView()
    {
        if (View != null)
        {
            var njView = View as NewJobUC;                            
          var contentJobDescription = njView.JobDescriptionCKEditor.GetHTML();
```

NewJobUC.xaml

```
<TabItem ...some code ... 
<local:ChromeWebBrowser  x:Name="JobScopeCKEditor" CKEContent="{Binding NewJob.JobScope}"   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="{Binding ElementName=canv, Path=ActualWidth}" />
</TabItem>
```

Comment: If you call `GetHtml` before the browser has finished initializing then you'll get that message. As you wish to access the `DOM` you should wait until the browser has finished loading, `LoadingStateChanged` is the option I prefer. You should also rewrite `GetHtml` to be an an actual `async`, what your doing Use `await` or `ContinueWith`, calling `htmlFromPage.Result` is a `sync` blocking operation and these calls aren't designed to be run in a sync fashion, as the `Async` in the name suggests.

Comment: @amaitland Can you check update from my question ?

Comment: You can use a https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1?view=netframework-4.7.2